# How to return rows that don't match another table?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using fluent nhibernate and nhibernate 3.1 and I am wondering how do I make a query to return results that don't match in another table.

Say I have 5 records from tableA and 3 records in tableB. Now 3 from TableA match the 3 from TableB.

So I want to return these 2 rows back as they where not in TableB. All the joins that I seen seem to look for matches and return the matches. I want to basically return the differences.

if say I had 5 records from tableA and 100 in TableB but none of TableA's records matched any in TableB I want to return all of tableA's records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not sure that I'm answering the right question, your description seems a little fuzzy...

There's a couple of ways to go about this...

I guess the simplest and easiest way would be to use a SQL query:

string sqlQuery = "Select * from TABLENAMEA A where a.field not in (select b.field from TABLENAMEB b)"

results = (OBJECT) session.ExecuteSQL(sqlQuery);

Bear in mind that I'm doing that from memory, I know the facilities to do this exist... And probably won't take you more then a minute or two to figure out...

Comment: @Gary - Basically I am trying to compare rows from Table A to Table B rows by id if(TableA.Id == TableB.Id) {continue;} else{return back;} So if both tables have the same Id I don't want that result back I want only results that where not found in TableA but showed up in TableB. I hope that makes a bit more sense.

Comment: Ok, so in your repository you ought to be able to query that.  Are you using HQL / SQL?  Bear in mind I'm sure there's a better way to do it... But I'm sure that will work...  Otherwise load both sets and do it in your domain logic...  So I think the sql bit from above will actually work...

Comment: @Gary - HQL and I would like to try to do in one query if possible.

Comment: Ok, well if your using HQL already just use a standard SQL string... See if that works and then if it's worth the time transform it into HQL...  I think I've answered the question... Have you tried doing this?

Comment: Sorry I meant QueryOver. I am trying to change everything to QueryOver instead of using a mix of everything.

Comment: Ok, I can't help you then.  You'll probably want to state that in your question...  Personally I would make it work however I needed too and then try to make it pretty...

Comment: @Gary - Actually the specs have changed for what I needed it for and I don't need to do this anymore but still would like to know how to do it in the future.